# Common legend in a multiple plot in R

Tags: r

```
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
# mortality age 50
plot(DataAge50$Year,DataAge50$DA_Female/DataAge50$EA_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age 50",type="l",col="green",cex=1)
lines(DataAge50$Year,DataAge50$DBC_Female/DataAge50$EBC_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=50",type="l",col="blue",cex=1)
lines(DataAge50$Year,DataAge50$DM_Female/DataAge50$EM_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=50",type="l",col="red",cex=1)
lines(DataAge50$Year,DataAge50$DNB_Female/DataAge50$ENB_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=50",type="l",col="black",cex=1)
lines(DataAge50$Year,DataAge50$DNL_Female/DataAge50$ENL_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=50",type="l",col="yellow",cex=1)
lines(DataAge50$Year,DataAge50$DNTN_Female/DataAge50$ENTN_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=50",type="l",col="beige",cex=1)
lines(DataAge50$Year,DataAge50$DNS_Female/DataAge50$ENS_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=50",type="l",col="orange",cex=1)
lines(DataAge50$Year,DataAge50$DO_Female/DataAge50$EO_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=50",type="l",col="blue",cex=1)
lines(DataAge50$Year,DataAge50$DPEI_Female/DataAge50$EPEI_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=50",type="l",col="grey",cex=1)
lines(DataAge50$Year,DataAge50$DQ_Female/DataAge50$EQ_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=50",type="l",col="chocolate",cex=1)
lines(DataAge50$Year,DataAge50$DS_Female/DataAge50$ES_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=50",type="l",col="salmon",cex=1)
lines(DataAge50$Year,DataAge50$DY_Female/DataAge50$EY_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=50",type="l",col="maroon",cex=1)

#Moratlity rates by age=55

plot(DataAge55$Year,DataAge55$DA_Female/DataAge55$EA_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age 55",type="l",col="green",cex=1)
lines(DataAge55$Year,DataAge55$DBC_Female/DataAge55$EBC_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age 55",type="l",col="blue",cex=1)
lines(DataAge55$Year,DataAge55$DM_Female/DataAge55$EM_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age 55",type="l",col="red",cex=1)
lines(DataAge55$Year,DataAge55$DNB_Female/DataAge55$ENB_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=55",type="l",col="black",cex=1)
lines(DataAge55$Year,DataAge55$DNL_Female/DataAge55$ENL_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=55",type="l",col="yellow",cex=1)
lines(DataAge55$Year,DataAge55$DNTN_Female/DataAge55$ENTN_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=55",type="l",col="beige",cex=1)
lines(DataAge55$Year,DataAge55$DNS_Female/DataAge55$ENS_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=55",type="l",col="orange",cex=1)
lines(DataAge55$Year,DataAge55$DO_Female/DataAge55$EO_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=55",type="l",col="blue",cex=1)
lines(DataAge55$Year,DataAge55$DPEI_Female/DataAge55$EPEI_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=55",type="l",col="grey",cex=1)
lines(DataAge55$Year,DataAge55$DQ_Female/DataAge55$EQ_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=55",type="l",col="chocolate",cex=1)
lines(DataAge55$Year,DataAge55$DS_Female/DataAge55$ES_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=55",type="l",col="salmon",cex=1)
lines(DataAge55$Year,DataAge55$DY_Female/DataAge55$EY_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=55",type="l",col="maroon",cex=1)

#mortality age 60

plot(DataAge60$Year,DataAge60$DA_Female/DataAge60$EA_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=60",type="l",col="green",cex=1)
lines(DataAge60$Year,DataAge60$DBC_Female/DataAge60$EBC_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=60",type="l",col="blue",cex=1)
lines(DataAge60$Year,DataAge60$DM_Female/DataAge60$EM_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age 60",type="l",col="red",cex=1)
lines(DataAge60$Year,DataAge60$DNB_Female/DataAge60$ENB_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=60",type="l",col="black",cex=1)
lines(DataAge60$Year,DataAge60$DNL_Female/DataAge60$ENL_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=60",type="l",col="yellow",cex=1)
lines(DataAge60$Year,DataAge60$DNTN_Female/DataAge60$ENTN_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=60",type="l",col="beige",cex=1)
lines(DataAge60$Year,DataAge60$DNS_Female/DataAge60$ENS_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=60",type="l",col="orange",cex=1)
lines(DataAge60$Year,DataAge60$DO_Female/DataAge60$EO_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=60",type="l",col="blue",cex=1)
lines(DataAge60$Year,DataAge60$DPEI_Female/DataAge60$EPEI_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=60",type="l",col="grey",cex=1)
lines(DataAge60$Year,DataAge60$DQ_Female/DataAge60$EQ_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=60",type="l",col="chocolate",cex=1)
lines(DataAge60$Year,DataAge60$DS_Female/DataAge60$ES_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=60",type="l",col="salmon",cex=1)
lines(DataAge60$Year,DataAge60$DY_Female/DataAge60$EY_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=60",type="l",col="maroon",cex=1)

#mortality age 65

plot(DataAge65$Year,DataAge65$DA_Female/DataAge65$EA_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=65",type="l",col="green",cex=1)
lines(DataAge65$Year,DataAge65$DBC_Female/DataAge65$EBC_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=65",type="l",col="blue",cex=1)
lines(DataAge65$Year,DataAge65$DM_Female/DataAge65$EM_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age 65",type="l",col="red",cex=1)
lines(DataAge65$Year,DataAge65$DNB_Female/DataAge65$ENB_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=65",type="l",col="black",cex=1)
lines(DataAge65$Year,DataAge65$DNL_Female/DataAge65$ENL_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=65",type="l",col="yellow",cex=1)
lines(DataAge65$Year,DataAge65$DNTN_Female/DataAge65$ENTN_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=65",type="l",col="beige",cex=1)
lines(DataAge65$Year,DataAge65$DNS_Female/DataAge65$ENS_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=65",type="l",col="orange",cex=1)
lines(DataAge65$Year,DataAge65$DO_Female/DataAge65$EO_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=65",type="l",col="blue",cex=1)
lines(DataAge65$Year,DataAge65$DPEI_Female/DataAge65$EPEI_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=65",type="l",col="grey",cex=1)
lines(DataAge65$Year,DataAge65$DQ_Female/DataAge65$EQ_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=65",type="l",col="chocolate",cex=1)
lines(DataAge65$Year,DataAge65$DS_Female/DataAge65$ES_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=65",type="l",col="salmon",cex=1)
lines(DataAge65$Year,DataAge65$DY_Female/DataAge65$EY_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=65",type="l",col="maroon",cex=1)

#mortality age 70

plot(DataAge70$Year,DataAge70$DA_Female/DataAge70$EA_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=70",type="l",col="green",cex=1)
lines(DataAge70$Year,DataAge70$DBC_Female/DataAge70$EBC_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=70",type="l",col="blue",cex=1)
lines(DataAge70$Year,DataAge70$DM_Female/DataAge70$EM_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=70",type="l",col="red",cex=1)
lines(DataAge70$Year,DataAge70$DNB_Female/DataAge70$ENB_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=70",type="l",col="black",cex=1)
lines(DataAge70$Year,DataAge70$DNL_Female/DataAge70$ENL_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=70",type="l",col="yellow",cex=1)
lines(DataAge70$Year,DataAge70$DNTN_Female/DataAge70$ENTN_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=70",type="l",col="beige",cex=1)
lines(DataAge70$Year,DataAge70$DNS_Female/DataAge70$ENS_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=70",type="l",col="orange",cex=1)
lines(DataAge70$Year,DataAge70$DO_Female/DataAge70$EO_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=70",type="l",col="blue",cex=1)
lines(DataAge70$Year,DataAge70$DPEI_Female/DataAge70$EPEI_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=70",type="l",col="grey",cex=1)
lines(DataAge70$Year,DataAge70$DQ_Female/DataAge70$EQ_Female,xlab=”Year”,ylab=”Mortality rates”,main=”Age=70”,type=”l”,col=”chocolate”,cex=1)
lines(DataAge70$Year,DataAge70$DS_Female/DataAge70$ES_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=70",type="l",col="salmon",cex=1)
lines(DataAge70$Year,DataAge70$DY_Female/DataAge70$EY_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=70",type="l",col="maroon",cex=1)
# mortality age 75
plot(DataAge75$Year,DataAge75$DA_Female/DataAge75$EA_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=75",type="l",col="green",cex=1)
lines(DataAge75$Year,DataAge75$DBC_Female/DataAge75$EBC_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=75",type="l",col="blue",cex=1)
lines(DataAge75$Year,DataAge75$DM_Female/DataAge75$EM_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age 75",type="l",col="red",cex=1)
lines(DataAge75$Year,DataAge75$DNB_Female/DataAge75$ENB_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=75",type="l",col="black",cex=1)
lines(DataAge75$Year,DataAge75$DNL_Female/DataAge75$ENL_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=75",type="l",col="yellow",cex=1)
lines(DataAge75$Year,DataAge75$DNTN_Female/DataAge75$ENTN_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=75",type="l",col="beige",cex=1)
lines(DataAge75$Year,DataAge75$DNS_Female/DataAge75$ENS_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=75",type="l",col="orange",cex=1)
lines(DataAge75$Year,DataAge75$DO_Female/DataAge75$EO_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=75",type="l",col="blue",cex=1)
lines(DataAge75$Year,DataAge75$DPEI_Female/DataAge75$EPEI_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=75",type="l",col="grey",cex=1)
lines(DataAge75$Year,DataAge75$DQ_Female/DataAge75$EQ_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=75",type="l",col="chocolate",cex=1)
lines(DataAge75$Year,DataAge75$DS_Female/DataAge75$ES_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=75",type="l",col="salmon",cex=1)
lines(DataAge75$Year,DataAge75$DY_Female/DataAge75$EY_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=75",type="l",col="maroon",cex=1)
# mortality age 80
plot(DataAge80$Year,DataAge80$DA_Female/DataAge80$EA_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=80",type="l",col="green",cex=1)
lines(DataAge80$Year,DataAge80$DBC_Female/DataAge80$EBC_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=80",type="l",col="blue",cex=1)
lines(DataAge80$Year,DataAge80$DM_Female/DataAge80$EM_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=80",type="l",col="red",cex=1)
lines(DataAge80$Year,DataAge80$DNB_Female/DataAge80$ENB_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=80",type="l",col="black",cex=1)
lines(DataAge80$Year,DataAge80$DNL_Female/DataAge80$ENL_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=80",type="l",col="yellow",cex=1)
lines(DataAge80$Year,DataAge80$DNTN_Female/DataAge80$ENTN_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=80",type="l",col="beige",cex=1)
lines(DataAge80$Year,DataAge80$DNS_Female/DataAge80$ENS_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=80",type="l",col="orange",cex=1)
lines(DataAge80$Year,DataAge80$DO_Female/DataAge80$EO_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=80",type="l",col="blue",cex=1)
lines(DataAge80$Year,DataAge80$DPEI_Female/DataAge80$EPEI_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=80",type="l",col="grey",cex=1)
lines(DataAge80$Year,DataAge80$DQ_Female/DataAge80$EQ_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=80",type="l",col="chocolate",cex=1)
lines(DataAge80$Year,DataAge80$DS_Female/DataAge80$ES_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=80",type="l",col="salmon",cex=1)
lines(DataAge80$Year,DataAge80$DY_Female/DataAge80$EY_Female,xlab="Year",ylab="Mortality rates",main="Age=80",type="l",col="maroon",cex=1)
[enter link description here][1]
```

How to write codes to set a common legend to these 7 plots:
I have tried this code but with insignigicant results

```
legend(“topright”,legend=c(“Alberta”,”British Columbia”,”Manitoba”,”New Brunswick”,”New Foundlands”,New Terrotories”, New scotia”, “Ontario”,Prince Edouad Island”,”Quebec”, “SaKastchewan””Yukon”),cex=0.8,fill.colors)
```

Please can you help me to improve my code?

Comment: Where can I find the datasets, e.g. `DataAge50` to reproduce your code?

Comment: there's *a lot* of repetition in your code, a package like lattice or ggplot2 would probably simplify your code considerably (and take care of the legend as a side-effect).

Answer (score 1):

There's no way this code will run without having tried or even seen the data, but it should give you an idea of how the process could be simplified:

```
# perform the repetitive normalisation of the columns of data
normalise <- function(d, varnames = c("A","BC","M","NB","NL",
                                      "NTN","NS","O","PEI","Q","S","Y")){
  dnames <- paste0("D", varnames, "_Female")
  enames <- paste0("E", varnames, "_Female")

  result <- data.frame(d[["Year"]], d[dnames] / d[enames])
  names(result) <- c("date", varnames)
  result

}
# combine all the datasets in a list
l1 <- list(age50 = DataAge50,
           age55 = DataAge55,
           age60 = DataAge60,
           age65 = DataAge65,
           age70 = DataAge70,
           age75 = DataAge75,
           age80 = DataAge80)

# apply our function to all datasets
l2 <- lapply(l1, normalise)

library(reshape2)
# combine datasets into a long format data.frame for plotting
m <- melt(l2, id="date")
str(m)

library(ggplot2)
# plot with facetting and automatic legend
ggplot(m, aes(date, value, colour=variable)) + 
  facet_wrap(~L1, ncol=3) +
  geom_path()
```

Comment: Ok Thank you for your help. I tried but it doesn't work as i was expecting. I'm going to find out more in the package lattice.

Comment: Ok Thank you for your help. I tried but it doesn't work as i was expecting. I'm going to find out more in the package lattice.In my plot i have in mind for X=Year from 1921-2009 and in Y=quotients as you seein my codes=It is mortality rates. I can inbox you the Database DataAge50. I'm absolutely new in r that's why i'm struggling. Thanks

Comment: people can only help you here if you provide a fully reproducible problem including data, and it is best to narrow it down to the most minimal example of what you're trying to do. It doesn't have to be your actual dataset, a dummy one is usually better.

Comment: Hi Baptiste, Please can you send me your email address by my email which is ntamjo2003@yahoo.fr, I will send you the database which is heavy excel database. It's difficult for me (because of the lack of space) to describe how it looks like by this forum. So by sending an email with the datafile, you can see it very well.

Comment: @ntamjoachille: That is just **so wrong** on **so many levels** that I don't even know where to start...

Comment: I run this code and i get the plots as i wanted...but my main problem is how to put the legend on this graph.Anyway, i will be delighted to have any help to improve my codes. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: please [read this first](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/471093), and try again with a **minimal, self-contained, reproducible example** (understand that you need to motivate people to spend time helping you -- chasing after your data or writing solutions that don't run because the problem was ill-specified is not fun. Neither is going through many lines of code that have nothing to do with the core of the problem).